# How to get hidden field values and assign in to the data table

Tags: asp.net

I am implementing this JQuery UI multiselect from http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

I have managed to get it to use in my asp.net page, but while i am submitting the button, the selected text shows only the last element checked.So i want to get all selected values in the hidden field.But how to assign the hidden field value to the data table?

Here i am giving my datatable.Previuosly i am trying to do the selected items to store in data table.

```
DataTable dtAssigners = new DataTable();
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("GIMID", typeof(int));
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(int));
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("MODE", typeof(char));
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("CreatedBy", typeof(int));
DataTable dt = null;

foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem list in ddlAssignedTo.Items)
{
    if (list.Selected)
    {
        DataRow drUsers = dtAssigners.NewRow();
        drUsers["GIMID"] = GIMID;
        drUsers["MODE"] = 'I';
        drUsers["UserId"] = Convert.ToInt32(list.Value);
        drUsers["CreatedBy"] = CurUsr.UserId;
        dtAssigners.Rows.Add(drUsers);
    }
}
```

But now how to assign the `hidden field value` in data table ?Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with these

```
DataTable dtAssigners = new DataTable();
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("GIMID", typeof(int));
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(int));
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("MODE", typeof(char));
dtAssigners.Columns.Add("CreatedBy", typeof(int));
DataTable dt = null;


string[] value = hdnFiledID.Value.Split(','); 
foreach (string va in value) { 
DataRow drUsers = dtAssigners.NewRow(); 
drUsers["GIMID"] = GIMID; 
drUsers["MODE"] = 'I'; 
drUsers["UserId"] = Convert.ToInt32(va); 
drUsers["CreatedBy"] = CurUsr.UserId; 
dtAssigners.Rows.Add(drUsers); 
}
```

Comment: string[] value = hdnFiledID.value.ToString().Split(","); ..error is coming ..its nt in the correct format

Comment: sorry it's is vb syntex,==>  string[] value = hdnFiledID.value.ToString().Split(',')

Comment: In c# its string[] value = hdnFiledID.Value.Split(',');

Comment: Now the all selected value is displaying in gridview..but again while m clicking on the id link in grid view..its not going to dat page..showing an error "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList". I want it ll go to dat page and all the items should selected in dropdownlist. Where z my error? Did u get my question or nt tell me ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47733/discussion-between-madhu-and-anil-shah)

Answer (score 0):

Have you some HTML? Check if the options are selected before submit. If not the multiple is not set to true.

This is taken from http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Next construct a standard multiple select box. **Do not forget the multiple attribute**:

```
<select id="example" name="example" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if You need Hiddenfield value to datatable..
first add the control

```
 <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" name="hddclick" runat="server" />

  Hidden1.Value = dt        // datatable object name
```